# Retrofit unable to set new Token to Header of Requests

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2, request-headers

I have a retrofit Client that helps me set a header for any requests i make to my REST APIs. On user login i get the token from the server and set this token to the header of the requests. I save this token to SharedPreferences so that i can get it anytime i need to make requests to my REST APIs. The problem is that anytime i set a new token to my SharedPreferences file when a new user signs in, it still gets the old token instead of saving this new token to use for future requests.

This is my Retrofit Client below:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String token) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create();

        okClient.interceptors().add(chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request()));

        okClient.interceptors().add(chain -> {
            Request original = chain.request();
            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header(Config.X_AUTH_TOKEN, "Bearer" + " " + token)
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();
            Log.d("Authorization", token);

            return chain.proceed(request);
        });

        okClient.interceptors().add(logging);

        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL1)
                    .client(okClient)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

this is my codes for setting and getting the token

```
public String getToken() {
    return prefs.getString(AuthUser.USER_TOKEN, "");
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(AuthUser.USER_TOKEN, token);
    editor.apply();
}
```

this is where i call my set token method to save the new token to SharedPreference

```
 authUser.setToken(token);
```

Comment: Please show the code where setToke/getToken methods are called. That one line is not enough to understand what’s going on.

Comment: @algrid i read a solution somewhere else but i have no idea how to implement it. This is what the user said "It's because the interceptor you added is still alive in the httpClient. Once you've removed the token (or pass a null to the createService() method, you need to remove the interceptor as well."

Comment: You have to write intercepter to append new token

Comment: @IshanFernando can you show a code snippet to write interceptor?

Comment: @LendingSquare I added the sample code

Comment: thank you @IshanFernando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely don't see how this is surprising. Your `RetrofitClient` is a confusingly (and arguably badly written) singleton. Let's go through a typical situation where this will fail.

You launch your app with a previously saved token. At first everything works fine. At some point you call `RetrofitClient.getClient(token)` and all requests succeed. After some time the server invalidates the token. You probably get a 403 response from your server, lauch the login screen again and update your token in your SharedPreferences. Here is where your problems begin. Although you saved your new token correctly, your `RetrofitClient` will do what singletons do and continue to return the first instantiation of itself stored in the `private static Retrofit retrofit` filed.

A quick workaround would be to add an invalidate method to your `RetrofitClient`. Something like.

```
public static void invalidate() {
  this.retrofit = null;
}
```

Call it when you get your 403 response, or when you logout.

PS: Please move the following line `if (retrofit==null) {` at the beginning of your `getClient` method. Creating a new okHttp client, for nothing, every time someone calls `getClient` is just wasteful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can write intercepter to execute each time before network request happen.Create new file as HeaderIntercepter

```
public class HeaderIntercepter implements Interceptor {
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    String token = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString("TOKEN","");

    Request tokenRequest = request.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();

    return chain
            .proceed(tokenRequest);
}
}
```

Add intercepter to okHttpclient

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HeaderIntercepter());
```

Comment: Sir, in this class how the `context` will be passed? If I am not wrong, we have to pass the context by constructor of HeaderInterceptor class from RetrofitClient class when the interceptor added. So every time we call the static method getClient() of RetrofitClient we need to pass the context. Is this process right? or have some other way?

Comment: Yes that's the way which I was implemented. I don't know other way.If I found anything , I will post it @HasanAbdullah